# "$parent" in multi-level directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to understand [a working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/nQq1zkqfxBJvPdYI5Jhu?p=preview). It can build a very simple json data by adding `name:value pairs` one by one with GUI; by a custom directive and its link function, it builds a html template as the right hand of the image below:

[image]

What puzzles me is `ng-model="$parent.keyName"` in the highlighted part, as well as `$parent.valueType`, `ng-model="$parent.valueName"` in other part.

1) What does the `$parent` refer to (in the code or in the example of the above image)?

2) Is there a way to show the value of `$parent` or `$parent.keyName` in the console or by adding something (e.g., `alert`) in the program?

Comment: Look at the documentation for scope for information on its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `$parent` refers to the parent scope (of any given scope). All scopes have a parent apart from `$rootScope` which is the top level scope. They can be created by any angular `ng-*` directive, including but not limited to `ng-controller`.

Generally speaking, it's considered bad practice to use `$parent` because it refers to the *immediate* parent scope which is subject to change. If the scope hierarchy does change (which it could do by adding a `ng-*` directive to a html element held in a custom directive template for example) then the hierarchy can be broken and `$parent` won't refer to the same scope that it once did.

2) **Yes you can**. In Chrome developer tools, if you `Right Click > Inspect Element` (as you have in the screen shot), you select the element. Then if you leave that element highlighted and go to the console tab and type:

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

That returns the scope that the selected element resides in. Then if you type:

```
angular.element($0).scope().$parent()
```

That returns the parent scope of the scope that the selected element resides in. And for what it's worth you can also do:

```
angular.element($0).scope().$parent().$parent()
```

and keep going up the scope hierarchy.

Also check out the **[AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)** chrome extension which allows you to look through the scopes in the Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Then, in the example of my image, which scope does the `$parent` refer to?

Comment: All of the classes marked with `class="ng-scope"` have a scope attached to them. In your screenshot, the highlighted `<input>` tag is within the boundaries of the scope created by the `ng-switch-when` direcive of the `<span>` tag above. So where you have `$parent.keyName` you are referring to the *next* scope above that which appears to be the one created by the `ng-repeater` (each item in the repeater having it's own scope).

Comment: I have [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875477/the-common-version-of-angularjs-batarang) about AngularJS Batarang, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Thomas That question appears to have been removed. Has my answer helped you with this question?

Comment: Oh okay. Pleased it helped.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this $parent refer to?

Parent refers to the scope of your parent controller. The image in your question doesn't give a clear picture so I will add an example for it.

```
<div ng-controller="EditorController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildEditorController">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Assume you have a property called editorsList (array) in your EditorController (which is the parent controller here), you can do something like

```
<div ng-controller="EditorController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildEditorController">
        Editors Count: {{$parent.editorsList.length}}
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can access the scope of your parent with the $parent.

Comment: I just added the code in the OP... There is only one `ng-controller` in the whole project, that's why I am wondering what `$parent` refers to...

Comment: The controller doesn't have to be added by ng-controller. It could be any directive.